# Why is the kivy window automatically 25% bigger than specified?

Tags: python, kivy, window

I'm creating a game in kivy and noticed that the window size is always 25% bigger than I specify it to be:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window

# screen dimensions, px
screen_width = 400
screen_height = 600
Window.size = (screen_width, screen_height)

class PlayGame(Widget):
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        self.touch = touch
        print(self.touch.x, self.touch.y)


class TestGame(App):
    def build(self):
        return PlayGame()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = TestGame()
    game.run()
```

Running this code, then clicking my mouse and running it down the side of the screen gives a width of 500 and doing the same along the top gives a height of 750.

I have looked in the kivy docs, but all it has for the window size is

```
Get the rotated size of the window. If rotation is set, then the size will change to reflect the rotation.

New in version 1.0.9.

size is an AliasProperty.
```

I'm not sure that any of this helps, expecially given that the window is not rotated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change a `Window.size`, kivy triggers some functions to update the window size. This part of the code in kivy is the reason behind your problem.

file `..\Python\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 420`

```py
    def _get_size(self):
        r = self._rotation
        w, h = self._size
        if platform == 'win' or self._density != 1:
            w, h = self._win._get_gl_size()
        if self.softinput_mode == 'resize':
            h -= self.keyboard_height
        if r in (0, 180):
            return w, h
        return h, w
```

if your system is windows based, window size is changed by this function `self._win._get_gl_size()`. You cannot stop it from changing it unless you edit kivy code or platform value, which is **not recommended** and may cause serious problems.

One solution is to find the scale and multiply it to x and y values.

```py
screen_width = 400
screen_height = 600
Window.size = (screen_width, screen_height)
scale = Window._size[0] / Window.size[0]
print(Window._size, Window.size, scale)

class PlayGame(Widget):
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        self.touch = touch
        print(self.touch.x * scale, self.touch.y * scale)
```